# Avoiding MonkeyRunner.sleep

Tags: android, python, automated-tests, sleep, monkeyrunner

I'm completely new to monkeyrunner and Android development in general. Following a bogstandard monkeyrunner tutorial, I was advised by someone to also perform the following sleep call after startActivity:

```
runComponent = package + '/' + activity

# Runs the component
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(5)
# Presses the Menu button
device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)

# Takes a screenshot
result = device.takeSnapshot()

# Writes the screenshot to a file
result.writeToFile('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\shot1.png','png')
```

...claiming that MonkeyRunner.sleep() is required to make sure certain actions are given enough time to execute. (But is 5 seconds even enough time on a slow device? How would I know?)

I know from experience in other languages that relying on .sleep is a terrible idea. I want to start prototyping some basic test automation strategies with monkeyrunner, and if I use .sleep all over the place, my tests will eventually accumulate arbitrary amounts of wasted time.

How can I use some kind of event-driven model for waiting for device tasks co complete? Are there common instances where I can't hook into certain events and I will have to leverage sleeping arbitrary amounts of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something more sophisticated than `monkeyrunner` to achieve your goal.

One of the alternatives is [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/) which has the ability to wait on conditions.

This example use **CulebraTester** to use the launcher drawer to start *Calculator*.

[image]

The generated `python` script is this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2018  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2018-04-13 by CulebraTester 
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


import unittest
try:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require('androidviewclient>=12.4.0')
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, CulebraTestCase
from com.dtmilano.android.uiautomator.uiautomatorhelper import UiAutomatorHelper, UiScrollable, UiObject, UiObject2

TAG = 'CULEBRA'


class CulebraTests(CulebraTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
        cls.kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': True, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
        cls.options = {'start-activity': None, 'concertina': False, 'device-art': None, 'use-jar': False, 'multi-device': False, 'unit-test-class': True, 'save-screenshot': None, 'use-dictionary': False, 'glare': False, 'dictionary-keys-from': 'id', 'scale': 1, 'find-views-with-content-description': True, 'window': -1, 'orientation-locked': None, 'save-view-screenshots': None, 'find-views-by-id': True, 'log-actions': False, 'use-regexps': False, 'null-back-end': False, 'auto-regexps': None, 'do-not-verify-screen-dump': True, 'verbose-comments': False, 'gui': False, 'find-views-with-text': True, 'prepend-to-sys-path': False, 'install-apk': None, 'drop-shadow': False, 'output': None, 'unit-test-method': None, 'interactive': False}
        cls.sleep = 5

    def setUp(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).tearDown()

    def preconditions(self):
        if not super(CulebraTests, self).preconditions():
            return False
        return True

    def testSomething(self):
        if not self.preconditions():
            self.fail('Preconditions failed')

        _s = CulebraTests.sleep
        _v = CulebraTests.verbose

        self.vc.uiAutomatorHelper.findObject(bySelector='res@com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/all_apps_handle,desc@Apps list,clazz@android.widget.ImageView,text@$,package@com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher').clickAndWait(eventCondition='until:newWindow', timeout=_s*1000)
        UiScrollable(self.vc.uiAutomatorHelper, uiSelector='clazz@android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,res@com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/apps_list_view,index@2,parentIndex@1,package@com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher').getChildByDescription(uiSelector='desc@Calculator', description="Calculator", allowScrollSearch=True).click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CulebraTests.main()
```

toward the end of the script, you can see (I just removed the Apps selector to reduce the size)

```
self.vc.uiAutomatorHelper.findObject(bySelector='...').\
        clickAndWait(eventCondition='until:newWindow', timeout=_s*1000)
```

which finds the Apps button, clicks it, and waits for the drawer to open, as a new window.

Close *Calculator* and drawer and run the script and you will see how it opens again

```
testSomething (__main__.CulebraTests) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 13.103s

OK
```

Comment: Thanks so much; yeah I arrived at a similar conclusion after meditating about it!